# Property 'age' does not exist on type 'Home' React/TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

React/TS newbie here. I am building a React component within the SPFX framework. `this.age` is getting the error, but `props.age` works fine.

I am getting a TypeScript error of:

> Property 'Age' does not exist on type 'Home' React/TypeScript

Code:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export interface IHomeProps {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  user: any;
}

export class Home extends React.Component<IHomeProps> {

  public constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.age = props.age;
  }

  public onMakeOlder() {
    this.age += 3;
  }

  public render() {

    console.log(this.props);

    return (
      <nav className="navbar">
        <div className="container">
          Your name is {this.props.name}, your age is {this.age}.
          {this.props.user.name}
          {this.props.user.hobbies.map((hobbie, i) => 
            <li key={i}>{hobbie}</li>
          )}
          <hr/>
          <button onClick={() => this.onMakeOlder()}>Make me older!</button>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }

}
```

Any idea where I am going wrong? :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare the property in the class.

```js
import * as React from 'react';

export interface IHomeProps {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  user: any;
}

export class Home extends React.Component<IHomeProps> {

  private age: number;
  
  public constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.age = props.age;
  }

  public onMakeOlder() {
    this.age += 3;
  }

  public render() {

    console.log(this.props);

    return (
      <nav className="navbar">
        <div className="container">
          Your name is {this.props.name}, your age is {this.age}.
          {this.props.user.name}
          {this.props.user.hobbies.map((hobbie, i) => 
            <li key={i}>{hobbie}</li>
          )}
          <hr/>
          <button onClick={() => this.onMakeOlder()}>Make me older!</button>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! - I will accept the answer when it lets me.

Comment: Ok, i`m happy that i helped you